# Creating shapes with CSS

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

At my [website](http://marc6294.keaweb.dk/facebook/) i want to make a speech bubble and found a great tutorial for doing so. But i want to do some changes, but i dont know how to.
Basicly i want to flip the little triangle horizontally, so its vertical on the right side instead of the left.
Here is the CSS:

```
.bubble
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 8px solid #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
}


.bubble:after
{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 38px;
    top: 100px;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent #fff;
}
```

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where. coz i m feeling like that i m bit confusing to understand your question.

Comment: For more shapes, check this 
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech bubble with arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299093/speech-bubble-with-arrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tve5t/) is a jsFiddle to show it working. Referenced from [**Pure CSS Bubbles**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/)

CSS

```
.bubble {
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.bubble:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-20px; 
    left:50px; 
    border-width:20px 0 0 20px; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: orange transparent;
    display:block; 
    width:0;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="bubble">
        nice
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try below css:

```
.bubble:after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: orange orange transparent transparent; // See here i change the color
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 38px; // see here for position
    top: 100px;
    width: 0;
}

.bubble:before {
    border: 25px solid;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px; // see here for position
    top: 100px;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. But i cant seem to see what made the different?

Answer (score 0):

For now i fixed it by flipping the element. Is there another method that is the correct way to do it?

```
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
```

Comment: Bro no need to that transform in this case because it easy to that using some tweeking in css code itself. see my answer once.

Comment: Also see my answer, no transform needed either. :)