# How to make a comment shape using CSS

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

Is it possible to make the shape shown below using CSS code?

I tried some things, but I can't make it so I need some help.

[image]

```css
#demo {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
#demo:after {
  content: ' ';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #333;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: yes, it's possible, what have you tried, show us the code....

Comment: Try this examples - http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168564/creating-shapes-with-css barring the rounded rectangular shape in that sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two triangles on `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
div:after, div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: -9px;
  right: 20px;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
div:before {
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 16px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

You could always use `svg` to make it even more easier.

```html
<svg width="108" height="68" viewBox="-2 -2 108 68">
  <path d="M0,0 h100 v40 h-20 v10 l-10,-10 h-70z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
</svg>
```

---

You could use `pattern` on the `stroke` instead of a single color.

[image]

```html
<svg width="108" height="68" viewBox="-2 -2 108 68">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pat" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="6" height="6" viewBox="0 0 6 6">
      <path d="M0,0 h3 l3,3 v3z M0,6 h3 l-3,-3z" fill="#E9D641" />
      <path d="M0,0 v3 l3,3 h3z M3,0 h3 v3z" fill="#85A03C" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0,0 h100 v40 h-20 v10 l-10,-10 h-70z" fill="none" stroke="url(#pat)" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
.speech-bubble {    
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 1em 0 3em;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    color: #000;
}

.speech-bubble:after, .speech-bubble:before {
    top: 100%; left: 90%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
} 

.speech-bubble:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 20px 0 0 20px; 
    margin-left: -20px;
} 

.speech-bubble:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-width: 27px 0px 0px 27px;
    margin-left: -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble">This is a speech bubble</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
div.icon {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.icon div.chat {
    width: 32px;
    height: 22px;
    background: #333;
}

div.icon div.chat:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-width: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    <div class="chat"></div>
</div>
```